# How to create a session variable and display another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In index.php I set a session variable in jQuery, and in this page I am getting my token id , but I want to display it in another page like home.php. So I am doing in home.php page

```
var val = $.session.get('Token');
    alert(); //**getting here undefined**.how can solve this issue please tell me any one
```

```js
(function($){

    $.session = {

        _id: null,

        _cookieCache: undefined,

        _init: function()
        {
            if (!window.name) {
                window.name = Math.random();
            }
            this._id = window.name;
            this._initCache();

            // See if we've changed protcols

            var matches = (new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + "=([^;]+);")).exec(document.cookie);
            if (matches && document.location.protocol !== matches[1]) {
               this._clearSession();
               for (var key in this._cookieCache) {
                   try {
                   window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, this._cookieCache[key]);
                   } catch (e) {};
               }
            }

            document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + "=" + document.location.protocol + ';path=/;expires=' + (new Date((new Date).getTime() + 120000)).toUTCString();

        },

        _generatePrefix: function()
        {
            return '__session:' + this._id + ':';
        },

        _initCache: function()
        {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            this._cookieCache = {};
            for (var i in cookies) {
                var kv = cookies[i].split('=');
                if ((new RegExp(this._generatePrefix() + '.+')).test(kv[0]) && kv[1]) {
                    this._cookieCache[kv[0].split(':', 3)[2]] = kv[1];
                }
            }
        },

        _setFallback: function(key, value, onceOnly)
        {
            var cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + "=" + value + "; path=/";
            if (onceOnly) {
                cookie += "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 120000)).toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = cookie;
            this._cookieCache[key] = value;
            return this;
        },

        _getFallback: function(key)
        {
            if (!this._cookieCache) {
                this._initCache();
            }
            return this._cookieCache[key];
        },

        _clearFallback: function()
        {
            for (var i in this._cookieCache) {
                document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + i + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            }
            this._cookieCache = {};
        },

        _deleteFallback: function(key)
        {
            document.cookie = this._generatePrefix() + key + '=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            delete this._cookieCache[key];
        },

        get: function(key)
        {
            return window.sessionStorage.getItem(key) || this._getFallback(key);
        },

        set: function(key, value, onceOnly)
        {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);
            } catch (e) {}
            this._setFallback(key, value, onceOnly || false);
            return this;
        },
        
        'delete': function(key){
            return this.remove(key);
        },

        remove: function(key)
        {
            try {
            window.sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
            } catch (e) {};
            this._deleteFallback(key);
            return this;
        },

        _clearSession: function()
        {
          try {
                window.sessionStorage.clear();
            } catch (e) {
                for (var i in window.sessionStorage) {
                    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(i);
                }
            }
        },

        clear: function()
        {
            this._clearSession();
            this._clearFallback();
            return this;
        }

    };

    $.session._init();

})(jQuery);
 
// Here i am set session variable

$.session.set('Token',"1") ;
var get_session_name =$.session.get('Token');
 alert(get_session_name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use some lib or jQuery plugin to work with cookie instead of that bunch of code in $.session? For instance, https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: why not just use a standard session cookie to store and retrieve the information ?

Comment: Wording, capitals

Answer (score 0):

you can create your session variable in a file(header.php) which should be included in every other file(home.php in this case)

So,create session like this

header.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      // session already exists
        echo "User ID:", $_SESSION['id'], "<br />"
    } else {
        // New PHP Session

        $_SESSION['username'] = "loginprocess";
        $_SESSION['id'] = 444;
    }
?>
```

Possible home.php

```
<?php require "header.php"; ?>
 <!doctype html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <?php
     if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
         $loggenOnUser = $_SESSION["username"];
         echo "Existing User: ", $loggenOnUser, "<br />"
     } else {
         $loggenOnUser = " new user";
     }
 ?>
     ...
         <div id="LoggedInUser" class="fluid ">
             Hi.  I'm <?php echo $loggenOnUser; ?> 
         </div>
```

**EDIT:**

Try moving your session initialization code to either header.php or footer.php and include header and footer in every other php page, this will allow access to the session variable in every page.

Include header and footer.php in other pages like home.php like:

```
<?php require "header.php"; ?>
.
.
//Body
.
.
<?php require "footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: i need jquery,i have one jquery varaible in that variable i need to set session